# how to parse csv by csv-jQuery and generate report?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jquery-csv

imagine that you have csv data like this that I can read them from a textarea on my web page:

```
A,10,USA
B,5,UK
A,2,USA
```

I am trying to use cs-jQuery to parse and process this data to get the following report:

```
A has ran 12 miles with average of 6. 
B has ran 5 miles with average of 5.
```

The code that I have written looks like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calculate').click(function() {
        $('#report').empty();
        var data = $('#input').val();
        var values = $.csv.toObjects(data);
        $('#report').append(values);
        alert(values);
    });
});
</script>
```

but all I am getting is `[object Object] [object Object]`...
any suggestion on what I should do? any way to do this with jQuery functionality?

Comment: Because `values` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 2):

this function [$.csv.toObjects()](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/blob/master/docs/api.md#csvtoobjects) return array of objects

> Useful for parsing multi-line CSV data into an array of objects
>   representing data in the form {header:value}. Unless overridden, the
>   first line of data is assumed to contain the headers.

You don't have header so you should use `$.csv.toArrays()` instead and iterate over that array:

```
$.each($.csv.toArrays(data), function(_, row) {
   $('#report').append('<div>' + row[0] + ' has ran ' + row[1] + ' miles</div>');
});
```

if you want to use toObjects you need to put header

```
person,miles,country
A,10,USA
B,5,UK
A,2,USA
```

and access it using row.person row.miles and row.country

Comment: oh, nice. the documentation of csv-jQuery is so poor. This is very helpful.Thanks. I just have to find a way to create a Hashmap of the data to count for the average.

Comment: you can count averge using something like: `var sum = 0; for (var i=data.length;i--;) { sum+=data[i][1]; } var average = sum/data.length;`

Comment: It might be too much, but I think you need to create a Hashmap that its index is the name (A,B,...) and the values are the total miles and the average.

Comment: @user843681 if you still have problems you should ask another question.